# Detached ExpoKit and Headless JS

Tags: react-native, expo

Cross-posting from Expo's forums:

I have been having problems trying to get Headless JS task to execute on a detached ExpoKit project (SDK25). I have used the React Native documentation to do this.

I have a broadcast receiver

```
public class MessageReceivedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "MessageReceivedReceiver";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onReceive");
        if (!isAppOnForeground((context))) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Not in foreground");
            /**
             We will start our service and send extra info about
             network connections
             **/
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, JSBackgroundService.class);
            serviceIntent.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
            HeadlessJsTaskService.acquireWakeLockNow(context);
        }
    }
...
```

A HeadlessJS Task Service:

```
public class JSBackgroundService extends HeadlessJsTaskService {
    final static String TAG = "JSBackgroundService";
    @Override
    protected @Nullable
    HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Log.i(TAG, String.format("getTaskConfig: %s", extras));
        if (extras != null) {
            return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
                    "Test",
                    Arguments.fromBundle(extras),
                    5000, // timeout for the task
                    false // optional: defines whether or not  the task is allowed in foreground. Default is false
            );
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

My MainApplication implements ReactApplication:

```
public class MainApplication extends ExpoApplication implements ReactApplication {

private static final String TAG = MainApplication.class.getSimpleName();

private List<ReactPackage> packages = Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
// new MainReactPackage(),
    new MyReactPackage()
    );

    private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
            return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
            return packages;
        }
    };
    @Override
    public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
    }
    …
```

In App.js I have:

```
…
import JSBackgroundService from ‘./services/jsbackgroundservice’;
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask(‘Test’, () => {console.log(“Got it”); return JSBackgroundService; });

export default class App extends React.Component {
…
```

And JsBackgroundService:

```
module.exports = async (e) => {
    // do stuff
    console.log("Running the background service");
    console.log(e);
  };
```

Based on logs I know that getTaskConfig is executed but for some reason, I don’t see anything in the console logs, looks like the javascript never gets executed. I have tried also running the Headless JS in foreground for testing purposes but to no avail.

Does anyone have any ideas what could I be doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I have debugged the problem a bit further and it seems that this [line of code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/HeadlessJsTaskService.java#L105) should get executed but never does. In other words the react context does not get initialized.

Any advices?

Comment: I have the same issue but using background-geolocation library. I have no idea why expo doesn't support headless JS

Comment: AppRegistry is usually not the cause of the error, there must be other error before that that should show the real error you are looking for

Comment: @nick26 I am trying to registerHeadlessTask in my detached expo app in app.js. But I am getting following error on start itself. "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react2.AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask')"

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks